# How to update a Sql Server table column while join two tables?

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to update a column while joining it to another table. I've used below query, but it gave me error.

```
UPDATE  TABLE_2 
INNER JOIN
      TABLE_1
ON     (T2.ID=T1.ID)
SET      TABLE_2.DEPT='HUMAN RESOURCE'
WHERE    TABLE_2.DEPT='HR'
AND T1.COMPANY =1
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: try using left or right join only instead of inner join..

Comment: Is it Oracle, MySQL or Sql Server?

Comment: i'm using SQL Server.and i've tried using inner join, left join. but it doesn't work.@M_M has solved this problem. check below Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, you're using table aliases that aren't defined anywhere (`T2`, `T1` etc) and that may very well solve your problem. If not, the correct syntax very much depends on SQL flavor.

For example, in SQL Server the syntax is

```
UPDATE T2
SET T2.dept = 'HUMAN RESOURCE'
FROM Table2 T2
   INNER JOIN Table1 T1
        ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
```

Although you don't even need a join here really, you just want

```
UPDATE Table2 T2
SET T2.dept = 'HUMAN RESOURCE'
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM  Table1 T1
        ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID])
```

In MySQL the syntax is

```
UPDATE FROM TABLE2 AS T2 
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 as T1 
        ON T2.id = T1.id 
SET T2.Dept = 'Human Resources'
```

Of Course, the `WHERE EXISTS` approach also works for MySQL

```
UPDATE FROM Table2 AS T2
   SET Dept="Human Resources" 
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  Table1 T1
            ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is MSSQL, then the query should be

```
UPDATE TABLE_2 SET DEPT='Human Resource'
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE TABLE_2.ID = TABLE_1.ID
AND TABLE_2.DEPT = 'HR'
AND TABLE_1.COMPANY = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE TABLE_2 SET DEPT='Human Resource' 
FROM TABLE_1,Table2 
WHERE TABLE_2.ID = TABLE_1.ID 
AND TABLE_2.DEPT = 'HR'
AND TABLE_1.COMPANY = 1`

Because when we update a table in joining then we use both tables in from close